# Google Tag Manager - Tags (type: event) stop working when browsing on a SPA

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

GTM tags that use the event type stop working properly as soon as a user browse my website. By "browse", I mean using client-side navigation, which doesn't refresh the page but only part of it (kinda the point of SPA)

You can reproduce this behaviour as follow:

- Install Chrome plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna to be able to see the GTM events calls in the browser console
- Go to https://staging.hep.loan-advisor.studylink.fr/idrac
- Click on the top-left IDRAC logo, you should see logs on the console (event fired)
- Go to https://staging.hep.loan-advisor.studylink.fr and select the "Idrac" choice from the select input, then click "Go", you should see logs in the console again (redirection detected, which creates a virtual pageview)
- Click on the top-left IDRAC logo, you won't see any log this time

I believe that somehow GTM binds some DOM events upon loading that get cleaned when the DOM changes due to SPA internal redirection, which reloads the DOM, partially.

Those GTM tags (type: event) I'm talking about are basically triggers based on HTML class/id in the DOM. When I use the GTM Preview mode (debug), I can see that there is no `gtm.linkClick` fired when clicking the logo, if I got redirected from another page using a frontend-redirection. But if I refresh the page and click, it works just fine.

[image: GTM Preview mode]

The simplest workaround I see is to disable client-side redirection but forcing a page refresh, but that's not a nice workaround and *kills the point of building an SPA in the first place*.

Maybe there is a way to force refresh the GTM script (need to clean it from the DOM and add it again because it won't trigger if already loaded), or to use a feature within GTM that binds everything again? I looked for the former and couldn't find any built-in function that would bind something to the DOM, and I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

Also, I may misunderstand what causes this behaviour, I'm just assuming here.

---

## Workaround 1 - Hack GTM and force refresh DOM bindings:

I found a workaround, which also proves that the issues comes from Google Tag Manager itself.

By deleting the `window.google_tag_manager` global variable *(which is obviously created by the GTM script)* every time the user browses the app, it makes the GTM script think it isn't yet initialised, and it will init once more, binding events to the DOM once more.

```
delete window.google_tag_manager;
```

> Beware! I also found out that doing so will mess up the number of events sent. The reason is still a bit unclear (I can see 2 reasons), but the side effect is that for every browser navigation done, one more event will be sent. For instance, if you don't do browser-side navigation, 1 event is sent (when an event triggers, which in my case happens when the user clicks on a link/image). If you navigate once through client-side navigation, then 2 events will be sent, if you browse once more (through client-side navigation) then 3 events will be sent in total, etc.
>
> It's still better than getting nothing when browsing, but adds a side effect.

Here is the (uglyfied) piece of code, from the gtm.js script (with my own comments):

```
Ol.Dc = function() {
        var a = y.google_tag_manager; // y is "window"
        a || (a = y.google_tag_manager = {}); // Lookup window.google_tag_manager or default to `{}`
        tb = a;
        if (a[Ha.f]) { // Lookup for google_tag_manager[$GTM_ID], if found then it means GTM was already initialized
            ub("Duplicate container installation abandoned: " + Ha.f); // Ha.f is the GTM ID as string
            var b = tb.zones;
            b && b.unregisterChild(Ha.f)
        } else { // If nothing found, then initialize
            a[Ha.f] = Ol;
            hi();
            th();
            zk.push.apply(zk, Lk()); // Do some weird magic, I haven't dig deeper, but basically bind stuff
            Ok(Ak, 0, "2:0,2:1,3:2,6:3,0:4,1:5,2:8,3:9,27:10,5:11,1:12,2:15,3:16,4:17,2:18,3:19,38:20,24:21,5:22,2:23,2:24,3:25,25:26,11:11,0:27,1:28,1:29,2:30,3:31,25:32,11:22,29:17,13:33,0:34,1:35,2:38,3:39,26:40,28:40,21:41,32:42,2:43,3:44,10:45,14:40,30:40,36:40,37:40,12:40,17:40,15:40,34:46,18:40,19:40,23:47,3:48,3:49,29:40,25:49,3:52,25:52,3:54,25:54,38:56,20:57,22:58,16:17,33:17,5:59,3:60,25:61,0:62,1:63,1:64,3:67,5:68,1:69,3:72,26:17,21:73,3:75,25:76,20:78,3:80,25:81,3:84,25:85,22:87,5:88,2:89,3:90,25:91,0:92,1:93,1:94,3:97,21:98,22:99,5:100,1:101,3:104,22:105,5:106,1:107,3:110,22:111,5:112,1:113,3:116,21:117,22:118,5:119,1:120,1:121,3:124,21:125,22:126,5:127,1:128,1:129,3:132,22:133,5:134,1:135,1:136,3:139,22:140,5:141,1:142,1:143,3:146,21:147,22:148,5:149,1:150,1:151,3:154,21:155,22:156,5:157,1:158,1:159,3:162,22:163,5:164,2:166,3:167,5:168,2:171,3:172,40:40,8:40,41:173,35:174,5:175,2:178,3:179,5:180,3:183,5:184,3:187,35:188,5:189,2:192,3:193,5:194,3:196,35:37,5:197,3:199,35:66,5:200,3:202,5:203,3:205,5:206,3:208,5:209,3:211,5:212,3:214,35:123,5:215,3:217,35:131,5:218,3:220,35:138,5:221,3:223,35:145,5:224,3:226,35:153,5:227,3:229,35:161,5:230,3:231,25:231,2:232,3:233,31:17,39:234,9:235,3:236,39:237,7:238,3:239,25:240,2:241,3:242,9:234,3:243,3:244,9:245,2:246,3:247,3:248,3:249,25:250,3:251,25:252,3:253,39:254,3:255,3:256,25:257,3:258,25:259,3:260,25:261,2:262,3:263");
            Ok(Rg, 1, "O,IAc,IAA8,IAAEwH,IAAAAAg__,IAAEABAAAc,IAAEABAAAoB,IAAEABAAAIG,IAEAAAAAACI,IAAkAAAAAAAY,IAAkAAAAAAAAAM,IAAkAAAAAAAAAgB,IAAkAAAAAAAAAAG,IAAkAAAAAAAAAAAD,IAAEABAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD,IAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8B,IAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEO,IAAEABAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAw,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABJ,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAx,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAED,KAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE,IAAkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY,IAAkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgB,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAG,IAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAI,IAAkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAw,IAAkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD,IAAkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAM,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAw");
            Ok(Ck, 1, "x,RQ,AAACD,RAAAE,AAAAIY,AAACAAAAAAAgB,AAAAIIAAAAAAC,RAAAAAAAAAAAQ,AAAAAAAAAAAAAAgM,RAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ,BAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAI,AAAAAAAAAAAAAAgEAC,AAACBAAAAAAAAAAAAg,AAACBAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ,AAAAIIAAAAAAAAAAAAg,BAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAQ,AAAAIIAAAAAAAAAAAAAg,BAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAI,AAAAIIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ,AAACBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE,AAAAIIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAI,AAACBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE,AAAAIIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAI,AAACBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE,AAAAIIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAI");
            Ok(Dk, 1, "IP,IgjB,IACAAgfAwBwH,IACAAgeAwBwDM,IACAAgUAwBADgTY,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAgH,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAxB,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAABc,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAAAP,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAAAAP,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAAAACH,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAAAACgD,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAAAAAAwD,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAAAAAAAwD,IACAAgWAwBQDAAAAAAAAAAgwB,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAO,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwf,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgD,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgM,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHwB,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAO,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAwB,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAAO,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAw,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAD,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAM,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAw,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAAAAH,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAAAA4,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAAAAAH,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAAAAA4,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAAAAAAH,IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQHAAAAAA4");
            Ok(ph, 2, "B:B::,C:C::,c:E::,oB:I::,AC:Q::,AM:g::,AY:AB::,Ao:AC::,AIB:AE::,IAG:AI::,IAY:AQ::,IAgB:Ag::,IAAG:AAB::,IAAY:AAC::,IAAgB:AAE::,C:AAI::,C:AAQ::,C:AAg::,C:AAAB::,C:AAAC::,C:AAAE::,C:AAAI::,C:AAAQ::,C:AAAg::,C:AAAAB::,C:AAAAC::,C:AAAAE::,C:AAAAI::,C:AAAAQ::,C:AAAAg::,C:AAAAAB::,C:AAAAAC::,C:AAAAAE::");
            Ok(qh, 4, "7:,14:,37:,66:,71:,96:,103:,109:,115:,123:,131:,138:,145:,153:,161:,165:,170:,177:,182:,186:,191:,195:,198:,201:,204:,207:,210:,213:,216:,219:,222:,225:,228:");
            for (var c = 0; c < Dk.length; c++) {
                var d = Dk[c]
                  , e = 1;
                d[ne] ? e = 2 : d[zf] && (e = 0);
                Nb[c] = {
                    firingOption: e,
                    state: void 0
                };
                Ob[c] = []
            }
            u("//tagmanager.google.com/debug");
            Ok(Vg, 3, "2,19,25,31,44,49,52,54,48,60,75,80,84,90,231,233,236,239,242,243,244,247,248,249,251,253,255,256,258,260,263");
            Ok(Qk, 3, "9,16,39,67,72,97,104,110,116,124,132,139,146,154,162,167,172,179,183,187,193,196,199,202,205,208,211,214,217,220,223,226,229");
            Ok(Rk, 4, "6:,13:,36:,65:,70:,95:,102:,108:,114:,122:,130:,137:,144:,152:,160:,70:,169:,176:,181:,185:,190:,36:,65:,95:,102:,108:,114:,122:,130:,137:,144:,152:,160:");
            Ok(Sk, 5, "arg0,arg1,function,instance_name,once_per_event,tag_id,vendor_template_version,vtp_attribute,vtp_checkValidation,vtp_component,vtp_cookieDomain,vtp_dataLayerVersion,vtp_decorateFormsAutoLink,vtp_defaultValue,vtp_doubleClick,vtp_enableEcommerce,vtp_enableFirebaseCampaignData,vtp_enableLinkId,vtp_enableUaRlsa,vtp_enableUseInternalVersion,vtp_eventAction,vtp_eventCategory,vtp_eventLabel,vtp_gaSettings,vtp_hotjar_site_id,vtp_name,vtp_nonInteraction,vtp_originalTagType,vtp_overrideGaSettings,vtp_setDefaultValue,vtp_setTrackerName,vtp_stripWww,vtp_trackType,vtp_trackTypeIsEvent,vtp_trackingId,vtp_uniqueTriggerId,vtp_useDebugVersion,vtp_useHashAutoLink,vtp_value,vtp_varType,vtp_waitForTags,vtp_waitForTagsTimeout,vtp_fieldsToSet");
            for (var f in Sk)
                Sk.hasOwnProperty(f) && "function" == Sk[f] && (Pk = f);
            var g = Pg("INIT"), h;
            a: {
                for (var k = [], l = 0; l < Rg.length; l++)
                    if (Rg[l]) {
                        var m = Sg(l);
                        k.push({
                            name: Vg[l],
                            type: m.type,
                            metadata: m
                        })
                    }
                h = k;
                break a;
                h = void 0
            }
            g.macroInfo = h;
            g.tagInfo = Vk();
            Wg(g);
            Hg();
            Zg();
            var n = y;
            if ("interactive" == J.readyState && !J.createEventObject || "complete" == J.readyState)
                jg();
            else {
                va(J, "DOMContentLoaded", jg);
                va(J, "readystatechange", jg);
                if (J.createEventObject && J.documentElement.doScroll) {
                    var p = !0;
                    try {
                        p = !n.frameElement
                    } catch (I) {}
                    p && lg()
                }
                va(n, "load", jg)
            }
            "complete" === J.readyState ? qg() : va(y, "load", qg);
            a: {
                if (!bl)
                    break a;
                cl();
                hl = 2;
                Zk = void 0;
                fl = {};
                dl = {};
                $k = void 0;
                gl = {};
                el = "";
                y.setInterval(cl, 864E5);
                y.setInterval(jl, 1E3);
            }
            Vl();
            Pl();
            a: {}
        }
    }
```

This is quite a hack, and doesn't play friendly with all tags, for instance, Hotjar that was loaded by GTM throws tons of errors about source-maps file not found and network errors to load files. I therefore removed it from GTM and I'll add it directly in my code, that's a small change.

I have no idea what side effects this hack may add, but based on my tests, all events trigger correctly no matter how deep I browse, and it works with previous/next browser features too.

I wish there was a way of doing this in a much cleaner way, like GTM would export a function so that developers can force refresh instead of doing this.

Comment: What about using a dataLayer object in which you would push your events ? That is currently google's recommended way of tracking and will provide you with a more robust solution :  https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#adding-data-layer-variables-to-a-page

Comment: @lkostka Because pushing things in the dataLayer still requires events for them to be actually sent. Just pushing things in dataLayer doesn't push them to GA for instance. Also, it requires a developer and add noise in the source code, while doing it from GTM dashboard allows anybody in the team to add those events, based on existing id/classes. Both ways are recommended, it depends on the actual usage. (And I'm already using dataLayer to store some data, which are later then used by tags when they trigger, but as said previously, it still requires tags/triggers)